# Programming an Frame by Frame Update Method in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently working with iOS app development and was wondering how you would implement a frame by frame update method similar to the one found in some game engines like Unity or Spritekit. I understand that you could just use the timer class, but that wouldn't update on every frame refresh.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you might be looking for `CADisplayLink`

Comment: Would making a new CADisplayLink allow me to do deltatime too?